# SP Page Builder php errors ( Undefined variable, Undefined property)

Tags: php, joomla

i installed a Joomla template and some errors are appearing in homepage, the Errors are related to the Sp Page Builder component.

How can i fix these errors?

Here's a document with the erros -  https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B1toGflgmV7fZi1SQ051QWZxZFE

And the site.php

```html
<?php
/**
 * Flex 1.0 @package SP Page Builder
 * Template Name - Flex
 * @author Aplikko http://www.aplikko.com
 * @copyright Copyright (c) 2015 Aplikko
 * @license http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html GNU/GPLv2 or later
*/
// no direct access
defined('_JEXEC') or die;

JLoader::register('JHtmlString', JPATH_LIBRARIES.'/joomla/html/html/string.php');

AddonParser::addAddon('sp_latest_posts','sp_latest_posts_addon');

function get_categories($parent=1) {
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true);

 $query
 ->select('*')
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__categories'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('extension') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_content'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('published') . ' = ' . $db->quote(1))
 ->where($db->quoteName('parent_id') . ' = ' . $db->quote($parent))
 ->order($db->quoteName('created_time') . ' DESC');

 $db->setQuery($query);

 $cats = $db->loadObjectList();

 $categories = array($parent);

 foreach ($cats as $key => $cat) {
  $categories[] = $cat->id;
 }

 return $categories;
}

function sp_latest_posts_addon($atts){

 extract(spAddonAtts(array(
  "title"         => '',
  "heading_selector"   => 'h3',
  "title_fontsize"   => '',
  "title_text_color"   => '',
  "title_margin_top"   => '',
  "title_margin_bottom"  => '',
  "show_image"   => '',
  "show_date"       => '',
  "show_category"   => '',
  "show_intro_text"  => '',
  "show_author"      => '',
  "item_limit"   => '',
  "intro_text_limit"  => '100',
  "column_no"    => '3',
  "image_alignment"   => '',
  "category"    => '',
  "style"           => '',
  "class"      => '',
  ), $atts));

  $app = JFactory::getApplication();
 $doc = JFactory::getDocument();

 // Database Query
 require_once JPATH_SITE . '/components/com_content/helpers/route.php';

 // Access filter
 $access     = !JComponentHelper::getParams('com_content')->get('show_noauth');
 $authorised = JAccess::getAuthorisedViewLevels(JFactory::getUser()->get('id'));

 
 $db = JFactory::getDbo();
 $query = $db->getQuery(true);

 $query
 ->select('a.*')
 ->from($db->quoteName('#__content', 'a'))
 ->select($db->quoteName('b.alias', 'category_alias'))
 ->select($db->quoteName('b.title', 'category'))
 ->join('LEFT', $db->quoteName('#__categories', 'b') . ' ON (' . $db->quoteName('a.catid') . ' = ' . $db->quoteName('b.id') . ')')
 ->where($db->quoteName('b.extension') . ' = ' . $db->quote('com_content'))
 ->where($db->quoteName('a.state') . ' = ' . $db->quote(1))
 ->where($db->quoteName('a.catid')." IN (" . implode( ',', get_categories($category) ) . ")")
 ->where($db->quoteName('a.access')." IN (" . implode( ',', $authorised ) . ")") 
 ->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' DESC')
 ->setLimit($item_limit);

 $db->setQuery($query);

 $items = $db->loadObjectList();
 
 // End Database Query

 $style == 'flex' ? $flex_style = ' flex' : '';
 $style == 'blog' ? $blog_style = ' blog' : '';

 $blog_style = $output  = '<div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-latest-posts'.$flex_style.$blog_style.' sppb-row ' . $class . '">';

 if ($title) {
  $output .= '<div class="sppb-section-title">';
   $output .= '<'.$heading_selector.' class="sppb-addon-title" style="' . $title_style . '"> ' . $title . '</' . $heading_selector . '>';
  $output .= '</div>'; // END :: title
 }

 $output .= '<div class="sppb-addon-content">';
 $output .= '<div class="latest-posts clearfix">';

 foreach(array_chunk($items, $column_no) as $items) {
  $output .= '<div>';
  foreach ($items as $item) {

   $item->slug    = $item->id . ':' . $item->alias;
   $item->catslug = $item->catid . ':' . $item->category_alias;
   $item->user    = JFactory::getUser($item->created_by)->name;

   if ($access || in_array($item->access, $authorised)) {
    // We know that user has the privilege to view the article
    $item->link = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getArticleRoute($item->slug, $item->catid, $item->language));
    $item->catlink = JRoute::_(ContentHelperRoute::getCategoryRoute($item->catslug, $item->catid, $item->language));
   } else {
    $item->link = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
    $item->catlink = JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_users&view=login');
   }
   
   $tplParams   = JFactory::getApplication()->getTemplate(true)->params;
   $params    = $item->params;
   $attribs   = json_decode($item->attribs);
   $images    = json_decode($item->images);
   $imgsize   = $tplParams->get('blog_list_image', 'default');
   $intro_image  = '';

   if(isset($attribs->spfeatured_image) && $attribs->spfeatured_image != '') {
   
    if($imgsize == 'default') {
     $intro_image = $attribs->spfeatured_image;
    } else {
     $intro_image = $attribs->spfeatured_image;
     $basename = basename($intro_image);
     $list_image = JPATH_ROOT . '/' . dirname($intro_image) . '/' . JFile::stripExt($basename) . '_'. $imgsize .'.' . JFile::getExt($basename);
     if(file_exists($list_image)) {
      $intro_image = JURI::root(true) . '/' . dirname($intro_image) . '/' . JFile::stripExt($basename) . '_'. $imgsize .'.' . JFile::getExt($basename);
     }
    }
   } elseif(isset($images->image_intro) && !empty($images->image_intro)) {
    $intro_image = $images->image_intro;
   }
  
 
  if($column_no == '1') {
   if ($show_image) {
   $image_alignment == 'left' ? $img_column = 'sppb-col-sm-4 column-1 pull-left match-height' : $img_column = 'sppb-col-sm-4 column-1 pull-right match-height';
   }
   if ($show_image) {
    $image_alignment == 'right' ? $content_column = 'sppb-col-sm-8 column-1 pull-left match-height' : $content_column = 'sppb-col-sm-8 column-1 pull-right match-height';
   } else {  
    $image_alignment == 'right' ? $content_column = 'sppb-col-sm-12 column-1' : $content_column = 'sppb-col-sm-12 column-1';
   }
   $h2style = ' style="font-size:180%;line-height:1.4;"';
   $img_wrapper_margin = ' style="margin:0;"';
   
   if ($image_alignment == 'left') {
    $inner_padding = ' style="padding:0 0 0 30px;"';
   } else {
    $inner_padding = ' style="padding:0 30px 0 0;"';
   }
  }
  
  // match-height
  $column_no > '1' ? $match_height = ' match-height' : '';
  
  // Flex Style
  if($style == 'flex') {
   $output .= '<div class="latest-post sppb-col-sm-' . round(12/$column_no) . ' columns-'.$column_no.'">';
   $output .= '<div class="latest-post-item">';
  
   if($column_no == '1') {
    $output .= '<div class="row-fluid">';
   }
   
   if(!empty($intro_image) || (isset($images->image_intro) && !empty($images->image_intro))) {
    if ($show_image) {
     
     if($column_no == '1') {
      $output .= '<div style="padding:0" class="'.$img_column.'">';
     }
     $output .= '<div class="img-wrapper">';
     $output .= '<a href="' . $item->link . '"><img class="post-img" src="' . $intro_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" /><div class="caption-content">' . $item->title . '<em class="caption-category"><span class="posted-in">'. JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_POSTED_IN') .'</span>'. $item->category . '</em></div></a>';
     $output .= '</div>';
     
     if($column_no == '1') {
      $output .= '</div>';
     }
    }
   }
    if($column_no == '1') {
     $output .= '<div'.$inner_padding.' class="'.$content_column.'">';
    }
    $output .= '<div class="latest-post-inner match-height">';
    

    if (($show_date || $show_intro_text || $show_author) != 1)  {
       $output .= '<h2 style="margin:0" class="entry-title"><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a></h2>';
    } else {
       $output .= '<h2'.$h2style.' class="entry-title"><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a></h2>';
    }
    if ($show_date) {
     $output .= '<div class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-date">' . JHtml::_('date', $item->created, 'DATE_FORMAT_LC1') . '</span></div>';
    }
    if ($show_intro_text) {
     $output .= '<p class="intro-text" >' . JHtml::_('string.truncate', strip_tags($item->introtext), $intro_text_limit) . '</p>';
    }
    
    $show_author || $show_category ? $output .= '<hr />' : '';
    if ($show_author) { 
     $output .= '<span class="post-author"><span class="entry-author">' . JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_POSTED_BY'). '</span> ' . $item->user . '</span>';
    }
    if ($show_category) { 
        $show_author ? $posted_in_category = ' cat-inline' : '';
     $output .= '<span class="category'.$posted_in_category.'"><span class="posted-in">'. JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_CATEGORY') .'</span><a href="' . $item->catlink . '">'. $item->category . '</a></span>';
    }
    
    if($column_no == '1') {
     $output .= '</div>';
     $output .= '</div>';
    }
    
   $output .= '</div>';
   if($column_no == '1') {
    $output .= '<div class="post-divider"></div>';
   }
   $output .= '</div>';
  
  // Default & Blog styles 
  } else {
    
   $output .= '<div class="latest-post sppb-col-sm-' . round(12/$column_no) . ' columns-'.$column_no.'">';
   $output .= '<div class="latest-post-inner' . $match_height . '">';
    
   if($column_no == '1') {
    $output .= '<div class="row-fluid">';
   }
    if ($show_image) {
     if($column_no == '1') {
      $output .= '<div class="'.$img_column.'">';
     }
     $output .= '<div'.$img_wrapper_margin.' class="img-wrapper">';
     $output .= '<a href="' . $item->link . '"><img class="post-img" src="' . $intro_image . '" alt="' . $item->title . '" /></a>';
     $output .= '</div>';
     
     if($column_no == '1') {
      $output .= '</div>';
     }
    }
    
   if($column_no == '1') {
    $output .= '<div class="'.$content_column.'">';
   }
    if ($show_date) {
     $output .= '<div class="entry-meta"><span class="entry-date"> ' . JHtml::_('date', $item->created, 'DATE_FORMAT_LC1') . '</span></div>';
    }
    $output .= '<h2'.$h2style.' class="entry-title"><a href="' . $item->link . '">' . $item->title . '</a></h2>';
    if ($show_intro_text) {
     $output .= '<p class="intro-text" >' . JHtml::_('string.truncate', strip_tags($item->introtext), $intro_text_limit) . '</p>';
    }
    $show_author || $show_category ? $output .= '<hr />' : '';
    if ($show_author) { 
     $output .= '<span class="post-author"><span class="entry-author">' . JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_POSTED_BY'). ' ' . $item->user . '</span></span>';
    }
    if ($show_category) { 
    $show_author ? $posted_in_category = ' cat-inline' : '';
     $output .= '<span class="category'.$posted_in_category.'"><span class="posted-in">'. JText::_('COM_SPPAGEBUILDER_ADDON_CATEGORY') .'</span><a href="' . $item->catlink . '">'. $item->category . '</a></span>';
    }
    if($column_no == '1') {
     $output .= '</div>';
     $output .= '</div>';
    }
    $output .= '</div>'; 
   }
 
   $output .= '</div>';
  }
  $output .= '</div>';
 }

 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';
 $output .= '</div>';
 
 
 $column_no == '1' ? $column_no_1 = '.column-1 {margin:10px auto;padding:0!important;}' : '';
 
 // Add styles @media rulepost-img
 if($style == 'flex') {
  $custom_style = ''
    . '@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {'
    . $column_no_1
    . '.img-wrapper a {font-size:150%;line-height:1.5;}'
    . '}';
  $doc->addStyleDeclaration($custom_style);
 }
 
 if ($column_no>='3') {
 $custom_style_3 = ''
   . '@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){'
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.'{width:33.3333%;}'
   . '}'
   . '@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){'
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.'{width:50%}'
   . '}';
 $doc->addStyleDeclaration($custom_style_3);
 }
 if($column_no=='5') {
 $custom_style_5 = ''
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.' {width:20%}'
   . '@media screen and (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199px){'
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.'{width:33.3333%;}'
   . '}'
   . '@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px){'
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.'{width:50%}'
   . '}'
   . '@media screen and (max-width: 767px){'
   . '.columns-'.$column_no.'{width:100%}'
   . '}';
 $doc->addStyleDeclaration($custom_style_5);
 
 }

 return $output;
 

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Throw it away, or complain to the developers they are releasing substandard code

Comment: share full error and only related code

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is many errors, but all of them are variable that have not been declared before using it, as example :

```
$style == 'flex' ? $flex_style = ' flex' : '';
$style == 'blog' ? $blog_style = ' blog' : '';

$blog_style = $output  = '<div class="sppb-addon sppb-addon-latest-posts'.$flex_style.$blog_style.' sppb-row ' . $class . '">';
```

In this case $flex_style and $blog_style are not declared, you should write this instead :

```
$flex_style = style == 'flex' ? ' flex' : '';
$blog_style = $style == 'blog' ? ' blog' : '';
```

That is just an example, but if you search a little you'll find other issue like this one.

Comment: Thank you! I think with this example I can solve most of the errors.

And in the case of the error Undefined property: stdClass :: $ params?

Can you give me some example of a solution?